# View 3,5" Display on all devices with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xcode6

I Running my app on Xcode6, i have a problem with the screen view with 4", 4,7", 5" (iPhone5, iPhone6 and 6+). it seems to display the screen of 3,5" (iPhone4)

```
println(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

**output:**

> display (0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0)

[image]

**And it display like that on the phone :**

[image]

**How can i solve ?**

Comment: are size classes supports on iOS 7.1 ?

Comment: it seems to not be supported

Comment: Bear with me, it sounds stupid.  Add a launch image to your project that is sized for the larger screens.  I can't tell you why it works, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add Launch Images for all devices and remove the Launch Screen File in project settings - it will fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your project navigator, under `Targets` click on `General` tab.

Inside that there will be `Launch Images Source` click on `Use casset catalog`. It will prompt for migrate & cancel. Click on migrate it will solve your issue.

[image]